# Call destructor when closing QDialog started from Q

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

I made a custom dialog that is derived from QDialog. If i close the dialog, the destructor is not called. Here is how i open the dialog `test` in the class `AWidget`. `test` is a member of `AWidget`:

```
//In AWidget:
test = new myDialog();
test->show();
...
```

If i close this dialog, the dialog `test` is (of course?) is not deleted/destroyed.

I have to do it in the destructor of `AWidget`:

```
Destructor of AWdiget:
delete test;
```

The `myDialog` consumes much memory. The user behaviour is to open a `myDialog`, work in it, close it but to leave `AWidget` open.

How do i delocate the memory/ call the destructor of `myDialog test` when closing it?

**Edit**

Is there maybe a better way than:

```
void myDiaglog::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event){
delete this;
}
```

Comment: `~myDialog();` inside the Destructor of AWdiget.

Comment: If i get it right, this is basically what is done now. I need something like an 'onClosedListener'(...){delete test; test = nullptr;}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to always delete the dialog after it is closed you may use [`Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum):

> Makes Qt delete this widget when the widget has accepted the close
>   event (see QWidget::closeEvent()).

```
//In AWidget:
test = new myDialog();
test->setAttribute (Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
test->show();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
test->show(); // async call
```

try this:

```
test->exec(); // blocking call
```

Neither `setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);` nor `test->setAttribute (Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);` helps in that case.